# Execute multiple shell_exec at once?

Tags: php, shell, shellexecute, shell-exec

How do I execute multiple shell_exec at once?

Also how do I switch each process to view output from test.php file? I need to know what each process (php file) is doing.

Take a look, example:

**index.php**

```
<?php
shell_exec("php test.php");
shell_exec("php test.php");
shell_exec("php test.php");
?>
```

That does not work how I wanted to be, first shell_exec (test.php) has to be completed first and then it will go to next shell_exec.

**test.php**

```
<?php
$section = rand(123,123);
$x = 1;
while($x <= 50) {
 print $section . ": " . $x . "\n";
 $x++;
 sleep(1);
}
?>
```

It does not output when shell_exec is executed but when I type `php test.php` manually in shell, it does output.

Or is there a way to open multiple shells?

This is a quick example, however I will be executing multiple PHP file to run CURL

Answer (score 1):

shell_exec("php test.php& php test.php");

Your best bet is to have those scripts log output to a file and actively parse it after running shell_exec().

Comment: output to a file is a good idea but there is no issue with file lock or like file already open?